# as concrete $p$-adic number

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be 2 or 7 in the following.
For certain reasons I need to find a "simple" rational **and irrational** numbers whose $p-$adic
expansion is a Laurent series with order $-5$
$$a_{-5}p^{-5}+a_{-4}p^{-4}+a_{-3}p^{-3}+a_{-2}p^{-2}+a_{-1}p^{-1}+a_{0}p^{0}+a_{1} p^{1}+a_{2}p^{2}+\ldots$$

with $a_{n}\neq 0$ for all $n\geq -5$, with $a_k=0$ for all $k\leq -6$.
Some $a_n$'s with $n\geq 0$ may be zeroes, but **not** on  a tail.
I also need a justification that the four numbers (ir)rationals/$p$ is 2 or 7 are as desired.

Comment: Do you know how to tell whether a rational number will have an infinite $p$-adic expansion?

Comment: @Arthur No, I'm a complete beginner in $p-$adic numbers but not so complete in real analysis.

Comment: @Arthur Please, see my edit.

Comment: For $p=2$ or $p=7$, how about considering $x=\frac{1}{p^5}+\sqrt[5]{3}$ and $x=\frac{1}{p^5}+\frac{1}{5}$?

Comment: @Mindlack Great! How can I see that $\frac{1}{p^5}+\sqrt[5]{3}$ is $p-$adic ? Namely that $\sqrt[5]{3}$ is ?

Comment: Use Hansel’s lemma.

Comment: I do not understand the last sentence in the post. @Mindlack: It's H**e**nsel's lemma.

Comment: @Torsten Schoenberg: right, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

A simple fact which should give you plenty of examples is that a $p$-adic number is $\in \mathbb Q$ if and only if its $p$-adic expansion

$$\sum_{i \gg -\infty} a_i p^i, \qquad\qquad a_i \in \lbrace 0,...,p-1\rbrace$$

is eventually periodic (or finite, i.e. has a tail of $0$'s); exactly as it is for $b$-adic expansions of real numbers, and basically with the same proof. Compare e.g. [Relating the base-p periodic expansion of a rational to its p-adic representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2323324/96384), [p-adic expansion of a rational number](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/458046/96384).

Now I'm sure you can come up with many eventually periodic and many eventually non-periodic sequences $a_{-5}, a_{-4}, a_{-3}, ...$.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot determine from the periodic sequence $a_{-5}, a_{-4}, a_{-3}, ...$ the number itself ...

Comment: To determine what rational fraction a periodic sequence represents, the answer by Lubin to the second question I linked to should give a complete answer. For example if $p=2, 1=a_{-5}=a_{-3}=a_{-1}=a_1=..., 0=a_{-4}=a_{-2}=a_0=...$, we get $p^{-5} \cdot( p^0+p^2+p^4+...) = 2^{-5}\cdot \dfrac{1}{1-2^2}= \dfrac{1}{32\cdot (-3)}=-\dfrac{1}{96}$.